# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8001010A): The message filter indicated that the application is busy

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nunit, excel-interop

I'm executing SQL Queries and saving the results in Excel using NUnit Framework and C#
I'm using ThreadPool which calls writeToFile function which opens the excel workbook, excel worksheet and writes all the data from DataAdapter to excel cell by cell.

My code is as below

```
foreach (string[] SQLQueries in SQLQueriesList)  
{  
    if (SQLQueries[1].ToLower().Equals("yes"))  
    {  
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(writeToFile),                                 
        string.Concat(sqlQuery, ':', string.Concat(scid, "_", SQLQueries[2]), ':', SQLQueries[2]))
    }
}
```

The exception that I'm getting is:

> The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8001010A): The message
>   filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))
>       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeInfo.GetTypeAttr(IntPtr&
>   ppTypeAttr)
>       at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.GetTypeAttrForTypeInfo(ITypeInfo
>   typeInfo)
>       at System.Dynamic.IDispatchComObject.EnsureScanDefinedMethods()
>       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject )
>       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue